# When adding a foreign key constraint, which direction is best practice?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Imagine I have three tables called `profiles`, `profiles_skills` and `skills`. It's a HABTM relationship, where a profile can have many skills and a skill can belong to many profiles.

I need to set up a foreign key constraint between these tables. My question is, what direction should the foreign key be? For example, do I do this:

```
ALTER TABLE profiles_skills ADD FOREIGN KEY (skill_id) REFERENCES skills(id);
ALTER TABLE profiles_skills ADD FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles(id);
```

Or do I do this:

```
ALTER TABLE profiles ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES profiles_skills(profile_id);  
ALTER TABLE skills ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES profiles_skills(skill_id);
```

I've never really followed a convention, I just do it the way I type it and haven't had a problem. But I've always wondered in the back of my mind if it even really matters.

Comment: The foreign keys must be on the "child" table, which in your case is `profiles_skills`. And yes, it matters. with the FKs on the separate profiles/skills tables, removing a skill from a profile would delete the profile.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a use case when it's impossible to have a record in `profiles` (and/or `skills`) table that DOES NOT have a corresponding row in `profiles_skills` table. But that's exactly what your second definition prevents. Therefore, it's not a question of 'best practices' - the first way is the only way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My question is, what direction should the foreign key be?

Foreign keys should be in the *junction* table (`profiles_skills`), referencing the *endpoint* tables (`profiles` and `skills`).

If you try to do it the other way around, you'll be able to "connect" **non-existent** profile and/or skill, which is exactly what foreign keys are supposed to prevent. It would also make it impossible to have an unconnected profile (or skill).